# Electron toast actions on Windows

Tags: windows, electron, toast

I am seeking an example of Electron notifications using toastxml actions. How can I check and act on clicking the action button? So far I found I can make notifications like this:

```
const toastXmlString = `
<toast>
  <audio silent="true" />
  <visual>
        <binding template="ToastImageAndText01">
            <image id="1" src="${path.join(__dirname, 'icon.png')}" alt="img"/>
            <text id="1">${app.getName()} \nHello World</text>
            <text placement="attribution">This small text on bottom</text>
        </binding>  
    </visual>
</toast>
`;
```

and use like this

```
let ENotification = new Notification({  toastXml: toastXmlString   });
ENotification.show();
setTimeout(function () { ENotification.close(); }, 2500);
```

What is nice about this is, this way notifications don't stack up in notifications center, if you want just last to be shown.

But how to define the actions part so I can act on them in main app? I failed to find such example anywhere, for Electron.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is really scarce indeed, but I was finally able to create a working example by putting together multiple sources of information:

- The [GitHub Pull Request that added the toastXml property](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/25401), which mentions the ability to receive clicks and actions via "protocol activation"
- The [reference page for the toastXml format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=xml), which describes how to add action buttons to a toast notification
- A [Code Project article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1187127/Windows-toast-notifications-without-a-COM-server?msg=5395948#xx5395948xx) which describes what the protocol activation is and how to enable it in a toast notification

With this, I was able to create a toast notification with actions which can then report back to my Electron application when clicked, either from the desktop or from the Notifications Center, and even when the application isn't running:

```
   let notification = new Notification({
        toastXml: `
            <toast launch="myapp:action=navigate&amp;contentId=351" activationType="protocol">
                <visual>
                    <binding template="ToastGeneric">
                        <text>Hello world</text>
                    </binding>
                </visual>
                <actions>
                    <action
                        content="See more details"
                        arguments="myapp:action=viewDetails&amp;contentId=351"
                        activationType="protocol"/>

                    <action
                        content="Remind me later"
                        arguments="myapp:action=remindlater&amp;contentId=351"
                        activationType="protocol"/>
                </actions>
            </toast>`
    })
    notification.show()
```

Now, to be able to get the clicks on the notification itself or the buttons, you also need to register a URL protocol for `myapp` as described in the Code Project article above. You set it up so it calls your Electron application and passes the contents of `launch`/`arguments` as argument.

Finally, to receive the arguments back in the first Electron process, you'll want to use [the single-instance lock mechanism](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#apprequestsingleinstancelock), since the protocol activation starts a new instance of the application as a separate process.

The benefit of doing it this way is that it's very easy to also handle the case in which your application wasn't running when the notification was activated (presumably from the Notification Center).

Comment: I'm getting "Unable to find Electron app at c:\\WINDOWS\system32\myapp:action"

Comment: can you share the full code or something, it's not working for me.

Comment: This is the closest I've gotten to a solution. I've got the protocol activation set up and it works great when invoked from start -> run. But when I plug it into the Toast XML it fails to bring the first instance to the foreground. It just flashes the taskbar icon. For some reason when done that way it does not believe that the second instance has allowed the first to take focus. Is this still working for you on Windows 11?

Comment: I've got a minimal example of this approach in Electron Forge:

https://github.com/RandomEngy/electron-protocol-notification

However in Windows 11 with the latest Electron, the app does not properly get focus when clicking on the notification. Something is going wrong in giving foreground focus permission.

It gets focus properly with Start -> Run `enrepro://test` or by putting that in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Romain's answer helped me get most of the way there.

However in Windows 11 with the latest Electron, the app does not properly get focus when clicking on the notification. I had to create a workaround [to send a keystroke event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-dummy-keystroke) to properly allow the first instance to take foreground focus.

Here's a [minimal example working app that implements protocol notifications](https://github.com/RandomEngy/electron-protocol-notification).